# Why Mathematica cannot apply The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus automatically?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, version-10, backslide

For some reason *Mathematica* cannot evaluate this definite integral:

```
$Version
(* 10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015) *)

Integrate[1/(Sqrt[x] Sqrt[1 - x + x^2]), {x, 1, 2}]
(* Integrate[1/(Sqrt[x] Sqrt[1 - x + x^2]), {x, 1, 2}] *)
```

although it immediately finds an antiderivative, which allows to evaluate it by manual application of The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

```
Integrate[1/(Sqrt[x] Sqrt[1 - x + x^2]), x]
(* (2 (-1)^(1/6) Sqrt[1 - (-1)^(1/3)/x] Sqrt[1 + (-1)^(2/3)/x] x 
     EllipticF[I ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/3)/Sqrt[x]], (-1)^(2/3)])/Sqrt[1 - x + x^2] *)

FullSimplify[(% /. x -> 2) - (% /. x -> 1)]
(* 2 (-1)^(1/6) (-EllipticF[I ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/3)], (-1)^(2/3)] + 
     EllipticF[I ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/3)/Sqrt[2]], (-1)^(2/3)]) *)

% - NIntegrate[1/(Sqrt[x] Sqrt[1 - x + x^2]), {x, 1, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
(* 0. 10^-31 + 0. 10^-47 I *)
```

What could be the reason that *Mathematica* cannot do it automatically?

Comment: It checks for bad points on the integration path. Often when the antiderivative has elliptic functions Integrate hits code that says, in effect, just give up.

Comment: I found [this blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus) discussing this problem in general. But in this particular case it looks like an algorithm weakness, because there are no discontinuities on the interval $[1,2]$.

Comment: It might be a bug. The basic logic is as I stated though: Integrate checks for patch singularities, and signals a failure in that checking code, so it gives up. I'll have a look at why the failure happens and whether it can be better handled.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau It worked in _Mma_ 8.0.4 and 9.0.1, but is broken in 10.0.2 and 10.1.

Comment: Perhaps a clue: if `int` is the antiderivative then on 10.1.0 `Limit[int,x->2]` has some issues. You get `Limit::ztest1: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity I ArcTan[(Sqrt[3]+2 3^(1/4) Im[Power[<<2>>]])/(1+2 Power[<<2>>] Re[<<1>>])]-Log[2 (3^(1/4) E^Times[<<2>>]+E^((I \[Pi])/3))]+1/2 Log[(Sqrt[3]+2 Power[<<2>>] Im[<<1>>])^2+(1+2 Power[<<2>>] Re[<<1>>])^2] is equal to zero. Assuming it is. >>` messages

Comment: but a bit of cheating  `Limit[Limit[int, x -> 2 + \[Delta]], \[Delta] -> 0]` gets you `2 (-1)^(1/6) EllipticF[ArcSin[(-1)^(5/6)/Sqrt[2]], (-1)^(2/3)]`

Comment: Yes it worked, but the ways in which it did so also caused considerable trouble for other examples. One issue is that the path singularity detection code was unable to handle the antiderivative and so it just let it through. Another was that when a limit could not be extracted the code would blindly plug in the value. Both caused their share of bugs...

Comment: ...such as shows up in this example. Integrate[Sqrt[(2*t)^2 + (4 - 3*t^2)^2], {t, 0, 2}] which was incorrect. The same changes alluded to above made this instead become unevaluated (version 10.0.1 I think).

Comment: The same behavior persists in 10.2 and is present beginning in 10.0.0, so I changed the tag.  (I'm not sure the [tag:version-10] is still appropriate, either.)

Comment: Shouldn't it be a bug then?

Comment: Also doesn't work in MMA 10.3

Answer (score 6):

As is well known, and has been discussed extensively in this forum, there may be problems in general with `Integrate[]` and the fundamental theorem of calculus, mostly due to discontinuities or other singularities in the antiderivative.

But not in this case for version 8:

```
$Version

(* Out[1]= "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 7, 2011)" *)
```

The integrand is:

```
f[x_] = 1/(Sqrt[x] Sqrt[1 - x + x^2]);
```

It is completely harmless in the range of integration.

The symbolic integral in question is easily calculated by *Mathematica* with the result:

```
Timing[Integrate[1/(Sqrt[x] Sqrt[1 - x + x^2]), {x, 1, 2}] ]

(*
Out[3]= {3.011, 2 (-1)^(
  1/6) (-EllipticF[I ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/3)], (-1)^(2/3)] + 
    EllipticF[I ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/3)/Sqrt[2]], (-1)^(2/3)])}
*)

% // N

(* Out[4]= {3.011, 0.646172 - 5.55112*10^-17 I} *)
```

The numeric integral is

```
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 1, 2}]

(*
Out[5]= 0.646172
*)
```

Done.

Finally, let's have a look at the antiderivative:

```
Integrate[1/(Sqrt[x] Sqrt[1 - x + x^2]), x]

(*
Out[6]= (2 (-1)^(1/6) Sqrt[1 - (-1)^(1/3)/x] Sqrt[
 1 + (-1)^(2/3)/x] x EllipticF[I ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/3)/Sqrt[x]], (-1)^(
  2/3)])/Sqrt[1 - x + x^2]
*)
```

There is no singularity in the range of integration as can easily be shown by plotting this expression.

I conclude that neither the implicit statement of Vladimir ("What could be the reason that *Mathematica* **cannot do it** automatically?") nor the statement of Daniel ("Often when the antiderivative has elliptic functions Integrate hits code that says, in effect, **just give up**.") is applicable in this case.

**EDIT #1**

The "regression" (Vladimir's expression in his comment) started earlier. In version 5.2 the integral is done correctly symbolically and even faster than in version 8.

```
$Version

(* Out[2]=5.2 for Microsoft Windows x86 (64 bit) (June 20, 2005) *)

Timing[Integrate[1/(Sqrt[x] Sqrt[1 - x + x^2]), {x, 1, 2}] ]

(*
Out[4]=
{0.2030*Second, 2*(-1)^(1/6)*(-EllipticF[I*ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/3)], (-1)^(2/3)] + 
    EllipticF[I*ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/3)/Sqrt[2]], (-1)^(2/3)])}
*)
```

Comment: Then it looks like a regression from version 8.0 to 10.1.0.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, this "happens" sometimes. I've already had some sad experiences with the transistion from 5.2 to 8. See my EDIT #1.

Comment: Hmph, not particularly happy with the output of `Integrate[]` myself. It could be a whole lot simpler than it is, but as I've said (grumbled?) a number of times previously, *Mathematica*'s handling of elliptic integrals is quite far from optimal.

Comment: As I have shown, things are ok in Version 8. I don't understand what's going on in Wolfram that newer versions can lose "knowledge".

Comment: Bugs are universal. Regressions happen. What bothers me is that Wolfram keeps all this under wraps until someone posts a question here. Then there is an unofficial answer by a company insider. Why does Wolfram not just periodically publish a list of known issues and their status?

Comment: One can only hope, @Ralph… "Aw hell, I'm positive nobody will hit this corner case…"

Answer (score 3):

Since I complained that the result returned by *Mathematica* is not as simple as I would like, I might as well post the closed form that I have. I will not write the derivation here, but the procedure is similar to what I did in [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/33500):

```
N[InverseJacobiCN[-1/3, 3/4] - EllipticK[3/4], 20]
   0.64617199330515618196

NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[x (1 - x + x^2)], {x, 1, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
   0.64617199330515618293
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I still don't have a computer with *Mathematica*, so I had a friend run both snippets for me. But I did derive the closed form with only pen and paper.

Comment: You are right, the antiderivative can be expressed as `InverseJacobiCN[(1 - x)/(1 + x), 3/4]`

Comment: @J. M.: thanks for providing the "miraculous" simpler expression. Maybe it is an advantage not to have Mathematica availble. More paper, pencil and brains perhaps ;-)

Comment: Dear Herr @Dr. Hintze, thank you for the compliment, but I would say it is less a "miracle" and more a careful reading of Byrd/Friedman. Probably, if *Mathematica* could do Carlson's integrals, I would not have to resort to trickery. ;)

Comment: @J. M. : please enlighten me about Byrd/Friedman and Carlson's integrals. And as for the other point : I noticed that sometimes I jump too fast from paper, pencil and brains to Mathematica ;-)

Comment: Dear Herr @Dr. Hintze, [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-52803-3) is a link to the venerable reference on elliptic integrals by Byrd and Friedman. As for Carlson, his dissatisfaction with the lack of permutation symmetry in the conventional Legendre-Jacobi elliptic integrals led him to develop his integrals; the [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.15) has pointers to his original articles.

Comment: @J. M. : thanks for the link. BTW the cover page of the book is in German ;-)

Comment: It is a Springer classic after all, @Dr. Hintze. ;)

Comment: @J. M. : please have a look at my new answer to your "this math.SE answer:" (your link here).